# Ionic workflow questions and facebook authentication issue

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

I'm trying to implement mobile application using Ionic. I'm following [this](http://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/ionic-facebook-integration.html), but unfortunately logging in doesn't work on real device. It works fine in the browser and the emulator. I did every step from the tutorial, I did the tutorial 2-3 times and still get the same error.

I am logged in successfully on my device but then I see the following screen:
[image]

I already have both urls as redirect urls in my application settings in FB.

```
http://localhost:5000/oauthcallback.html
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
```

I tried to debug OpenFB with alerts. I can see "cordova events" alert but then I have alerts on the first lines of `loginWindow_loadStartHandler` and `loginWindow_exitHandler` but they are not executed. I guess that the problem is there but I have no idea how to fix it.

```
if (runningInCordova) {
  alert("cordova events");
  loginWindow.addEventListener('loadstart', loginWindow_loadStartHandler);
  loginWindow.addEventListener('exit', loginWindow_exitHandler);
}
```

***Also I have some questions about Ionic and Phonegap.***

I use Ubuntu and I am trying to build iOS and Android applications. 
My application's structure is:

```
app/
 hooks/
 platforms/
 plugins/
 scss/
 www/
```

Also I have InAppBrowser plugin:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

but this plugin is not part of app/www folder.

I am trying to build a phonegap application in their site. I made a .rar file of the app/www folder content and upload it. Everything seems to be fine. But in Phonegap site when I click **PLUGINS**, I see `This application has no plugins.` How should I add `inappbrowser` to the application, maybe that is the reason why my FB authentication doesn't work. If I build the whole app folder, again I see the same message - `This application has no plugins.`

So when create an archive file of the content for Phonegap, which folder I should archive - the whole app folder with all subfolders or only app/www? What is the correct flow? Also how crossplatform app should now about added plugins?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today, if someone is still looking for the solution for this:

> loginWindow.addEventListener('loadstart',
>   loginWindow_loadStartHandler);

is implemented in the js file, but the loadstart event never fires on my Android (but works on WindowsPhone cordova javascript app), instead i added:

> loginWindow.addEventListener('loadstop',
>   loginWindow_loadStartHandler);

,which works on both Android and WP (with InAppBrowser 1.2.0), IOS test is still ahead.